# Making a latin square

Tags: python-3.x, latin-square

Im trying to get a question done for some school homework, and im just having the worst case of brain farts humanity has ever seen.  The the question asks for three things.

• It reads a number N on a line by itself. This will be the order of a Latin square. The order must be a
positive integer, e.g., N > 0.

• It reads N lines of N of numbers, i.e., it reads console input for a square of numbers.

• It checks whether the sequence of numbers is a Latin square or not. Your program should display the
message “yes” if it satisfies the above criteria, or “no” if it does not.

My current code is this:

```
def makelatin():

order = int(input("Enter the order of the latin square: "))

latin = [int(x) for x in input("enter the latin square with spaces inbetween the numbers: ").split()]




def checklatin(latin) :

    numbers = set(range(1, len(latin) + 1))

    if (any(set(row) != numbers for row in latin) or any(set(col) != numbers for col in zip(*latin))) :

        print ("False")

    print ("True")

checklatin(a)
```

So what ive thought of is this, Make a latin square, then check it.  My probelm is, im currently stuck on the makelatin part. The user inputs the order of the latin square, and then they enter the square in a input.

Example:

```
"enter order of square" = 3

"enter the square" = 3 2 1 1 3 2 2 1 3
```

Which would make a latin square like this

```
3 2 1 

1 3 2 

2 1 3
```

This doesn't need to make a square, but it does help me visualize it a bit better.

So my main question is, is there a good way to make the user entered latin square into an actual latin square?

To note, im not looking for any answers, im just wanting some help to get past my mental block.

Comment: actual latin square as in the final code block?

Comment: it doesn't actually have to make the square, but it needs to check if it fits the parameters of a latin square.  i just figure it would be easier to make the square and then check it.

Comment: You can't break up the `if` like that without a `\ `

Comment: sorry, I didnt see it broke up, it isnt like that in my code.

Comment: Are you asking for how to do the input, or just not showing the code?

Comment: @stickupmybutt. Please show your actual code. This is pointless if you don't

Comment: im just confused on how would be the best way to do it.  i know how to get the user info, but im just so lost on how to use the order to make the square.

Comment: I have shown my entire code,

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand your question. Your code is good enough to collect a latin square from the user, I've just tested it. What is it then you're looking for?

Comment: it collects the latin square, but i want to test IF its a latin square.

Answer (score 2):

I got it, sorry to bug you guys!  the answer is this

```
def makelatin():

    order = int(input("Enter the order of the latin square: "))
    latin = [int(x) for x in input("enter the latin square with spaces inbetween the numbers: ").split()]

    return (list(zip(*(iter(latin),) * order)))


def checklatin(latin) :
    numbers = set(range(1, len(latin) + 1))
    if (any(set(row) != numbers for row in latin) or any(set(col) != numbers for col in zip(*latin))) :
        print ("False")
    else:
        print ("True")

#a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [2, 3, 5, 1, 4],
     [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
     [4, 1, 2, 5, 3],
     [5, 4, 1, 3, 2]]


checklatin(makelatin())
```

Comment: `(list(zip(*(iter(latin),) * order)))` is nice but very terse, to the point of being a bit obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind I use matlab:

```
n=5;
% create an empty matrix of NaNs.
latinSquare=nan(n);
% fill the 1st column.
latinSquare(:,1)=1:n;

% define a variable of how we want to shift the 1s column to fill the remaining columns.
% ballanced order:
shiftsize=(.5-mod(1:n-1,2))/.5.*ceil((1:n-1)/2);
% normal order:
%shiftsize=n-1:-1:1;


for col=2:n
    latinSquare(:,col)=circshift((1:n)',shiftsize(col-1));
end
```

and this will be the output for the ballanced latin square:

```
ans =

 1     2     5     3     4
 2     3     1     4     5
 3     4     2     5     1
 4     5     3     1     2
 5     1     4     2     3
```

this is the normal Latin square:

```
ans =

 1     2     3     4     5
 2     3     4     5     1
 3     4     5     1     2
 4     5     1     2     3
 5     1     2     3     4
```

now I rewrite it with python:

```
def latin_square(n, mod='ballanced'):

  import numpy as np

  mat = np.empty((n,n,))*np.nan

  mat[:,0] = range(1,n+1)

  if mod=='ballanced':
    shift = (.5-np.mod(np.array(range(1,n)),2))/.5*np.ceil(np.array(range(1,n))/2)
    shift = shift.astype(int)
  elif mod=='normal':
    shift = np.array(range(n-1, -1, -1))

  for col in range(1, n):
    mat[:, col] = np.roll(mat[:,0], shift[col-1])
    
  return(mat)
    

latin_square(6)

array([[1., 2., 6., 3., 5., 4.],
   [2., 3., 1., 4., 6., 5.],
   [3., 4., 2., 5., 1., 6.],
   [4., 5., 3., 6., 2., 1.],
   [5., 6., 4., 1., 3., 2.],
   [6., 1., 5., 2., 4., 3.]])
```